# Object is comma separated. How to parse it with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Objects under "variable" are comma separated. How do I extract 'year' and 'rate' out of it? I am using javascript.

```
 {
    "variable": {
        "1,0": [{
                "year": 1,
                "rate": 6.83
            },
            {
                "year": 3,
                "rate": 6.83
            },
            {
                "year": 5,
                "rate": 7.05
            },
            {
                "year": 10,
                "rate": 8.3
            }
        ],
        "2,0": [{
                "year": 1,
                "rate": 6.83
            },
            {
                "year": 3,
                "rate": 8.3
            },
            {
                "year": 5,
                "rate": 8.3
            },
            {
                "year": 10,
                "rate": 8.45
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). That's just a plain object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is an object with an attribute named "variable". This attribute is an object with 2 attributes "1,0" and "2,0". Each of these attributes contains an array of objects.

**Because the attribute names "1,0" and "2,0" are numeric you have to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of dot notation.**

If you want to access the first `year` attribute in "1,0" you could do it with (assuming the object is called `obj`)

```
obj.variable['1,0'][0].year
```

Comment: Glad to help @DhirajAggarwal Feel free to mark the answer as "Accepted" by clicking the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = {  
   "variable":{  
      "1,0":[  
         {  
            "year":1,
            "rate":6.83
         },
         {  
            "year":3,
            "rate":6.83
         },
         {  
            "year":5,
            "rate":7.05
         },
         {  
            "year":10,
            "rate":8.3
         }
      ],
      "2,0":[  
         {  
            "year":1,
            "rate":6.83
         },
         {  
            "year":3,
            "rate":8.3
         },
         {  
            "year":5,
            "rate":8.3
         },
         {  
            "year":10,
            "rate":8.45
         }
      ]
   }
}
    
    
    
    for(i in obj.variable){
    obj.variable[i].forEach(function(value,key){
       console.log(value.year);
        console.log(value.rate);
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access an object properties also by using the bracket notation.
Supposing you saved your json in a variable:

```js
let json = {
  variable: {
    "1,0": [
      { year: 1, rate: 6.83 },
      { year: 3, rate: 6.83 },
      { year: 5, rate: 7.05 },
      { year: 10, rate: 8.3 }
    ],
    "2,0": [
      { year: 1, rate: 6.83 },
      { year: 3, rate: 8.3 },
      { year: 5, rate: 8.3 },
      { year: 10, rate: 8.45 }
    ]
  }
};

 
console.log(json.variable["1,0"][0].year);
```